# What is default C calling convention on 32 bit Linux and 64 bit Linux (Intel desktop CPU)?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

What is default calling convention for a static function say:

```
static void PrintHelloWorld(char* s) { }
```

under

Linux:

```
#36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and with

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3 Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-23-generic
```

Comment: There's no "general case answer". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: @duskwuff Edited question for specific answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under the architecture and compiler you have listed (Linux x86_64), the calling convention described in the [System V AMD64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) is used.

Under Linux i386, the calling convention described in the [System V i386 ABI](http://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-i386.pdf) is used.